# Move multiple files into their own folder according to their filename

Tags: windows-10, script

I'm in need of a fast way to move multiple files into their own folder by their filename. I'm running Windows 10 but if needed I could easily make a Linux VM.

Unfortunately I have no idea how to make a script and I've found next to no programs that could help me. Here's the situation.

```
01 (1).png
02 (1).png
03 (1).png
```

I want those files to go to a folder named "FILE 1". The list goes on...

```
01 (2).png
02 (2).png
03 (2).png
```

...and these should move to a folder named "FILE 2" and so on, I think the list goes on to (85) or something.

If someone could guide me on how do this I'd be eternally grateful.

Comment: What do source & destinaton paths look like? Afe all source files in one folder? Are the new folders being created by as sub-folders of the source folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following `.bat` file will do what you asked, while also renaming files
from `02 (3).png` to `02.png`:

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for %%F in (*.png) do (
  for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=(). " %%A in ("%%F") do (
    set "DIR=FILE %%B"
    if not exist "!DIR!" mkdir "!DIR!"
    move "%%F" "!DIR!\%%A.png"
  )
)
```

If you do not wish to rename the files, replace `"!DIR!\%%A.png"` above by
`"!DIR!\%%F"`.